# neo4j-import tool documentation for neo4j 3.0

Tags: windows, neo4j

Is there any documentation available for the neo4j-import command line tool for neo4j 3.0? I've used the command line tool and the powershell script version in neo4j 2.3.3, but the same commands are not working for neo4j 3.0 *when using the Windows 64bit version*. I *can* successfully run the import using The Linux/UNIX (tar) version of neo4j 3.0.

```
bin\neo4j-import.bat --into "C:\Neo4j\TBR_3\data\databases\graph.db" --nodes "C:\Developer\Neo4j_Staging\TBR\header_person_neo4j.psv,C:\Developer\Neo4j_Staging\TBR\nodes_person_neo4j.psv" --nodes "C:\Developer\Neo4j_Staging\TBR\header_address_neo4j.psv,C:\Developer\Neo4j_Staging\TBR\nodes_address_neo4j.psv" --nodes "C:\Developer\Neo4j_Staging\TBR\header_telephone_neo4j.psv,C:\Developer\Neo4j_Staging\TBR\nodes_telephone_neo4j.psv" --relationships "C:\Developer\Neo4j_Staging\TBR\header_personAddress_neo4j.psv,C:\Developer\Neo4j_Staging\TBR\rels_personAddress_neo4j.psv" --relationships "C:\Developer\Neo4j_Staging\TBR\header_personTelephone_neo4j.psv,C:\Developer\Neo4j_Staging\TBR\rels_personTelephone_neo4j.psv" --delimiter "|"
```

gives me:

```
'")"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

To get an idea of the structure of the headers I'm using, the header_person_neo4j.psv file contains:

```
masterIndividualKey:ID(Person)|matchIndividualKey:int|individualKey:int|stdTitle:string[]|stdTitleAlias:string[]|stdForename:string[]|stdForenameAlias:string[]|stdForenameNYSIIS:string[]|stdForenameSoundex:string[]|stdForenameDoubleMetaphone:string[]|stdOthername:string[]|stdOthernameAlias:string[]|stdOthernameNYSIIS:string[]|stdOthernameSoundex:string[]|stdOthernameDoubleMetaphone:string[]|stdSurname:string[]|stdSurnameNYSIIS:string[]|stdSurnameSoundex:string[]|stdSurnameDoubleMetaphone:string[]|stdGender:string[]|stdNameQuality:int[]|stdDOB:string|stdDOBMax:string|stdDOBMin:string|stdHierarchy:int[]|stdRecency:string[]|stdRecencyMax:string|stdHierarchyMin:int|stdPreferredName:int|stdGenderCombined:string|title:string|forename:string|surname:string|gender:string|nameScore:int|dateOfBirth:string|dateOfDeath:string|deathDateActual:string|:LABEL
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [import tool documentation](http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tutorial/import-tool/) which explains with examples. The problem is with your file URL, in Windows you have to use different file URL for example as bellow:

```
neo4j-import --into C:/neo4j/data/databases/MEDIUM_GRAPH --id-type integer --stacktrace --nodes:STORE "C:/nodes/store_header.csv,C:/nodes/dimstore.csv"
```

This [blog](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-import-csv/#_super_fast_batch_importer_for_huge_datasets) is also useful to understand different methods tricks. All data by default are imported as `string` in neo4j so you do not need to specify string data type in your csv headers. Refer to this [document](http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tools/import/file-header-format/) to get information about csv file header format.